# How to paraphrase this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, writing-style, parentheses

I am told that these three sentences imply the same meaning and I can put them together: any idea pleas!

```
 Still, domy and duny products have not been evaluated to date with respect to the 
 most recent products(smhs) at a global scale. That motivates us to do global inter-
 comparison between domy and duny products using smhs products.Our study evaluated 
 domy and duny products with respect to smhs products during the 1989–2000 period.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While domy and duny products were evaluated against smhs products in 1989-2000, a global evaluation (or study) needs to be carried out against the more recent smhs products .

Comment: thanks but they were not evaluated in 1989-2000. we evaluated them